# How can I plot this data as a surface plot in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the following data as a surface plot. The mesh library or persp3D seems to do what I want, but it seems I cannot find the correct way to input my data. I pasted some sample data below.

```
  V1   V2   V3
1 1.01 1.30 -113.7410   
2 1.01 1.25 -113.7540   
3 1.01 1.22 -113.7589    
4 1.01 1.20 -113.7605  
5 1.03 1.30 -113.7458  
6 1.03 1.25 -113.7590   
7 1.01 1.20 -113.7605
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data doesn't make sense, you basically need to make a grid of points (equally spaced!) on your x, y axis and a single z coordinate. I suppose you could use interpolation to get some kind of surface plot based on your data.

In the example below I've used `interp` from `akima` to interpolate the values based on the mean, and it will produce a grid of points in the format that you're after.

```
library(rgl)
library(akima)

dat<-data.frame(V1=c(1.01,1.01,1.01,1.01,1.03,1.03,1.01),
              V2=c(1.30,1.25,1.22,1.20,1.30,1.25,1.20),
              V3=c(-113.7410,-113.7540,-113.7589,-113.7605,-113.7458,-113.7590,-113.7605))

s = interp(dat$V1, dat$V2, dat$V3, duplicate="mean")
persp3d(s$x, s$y, s$z)
```

Output:

[image]